# Pivot_wider is not working as expected with spark_apply in R

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

Pivot_wider is not working as expected with spark_apply

[https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/3304]

```
d <- data. Frame(
c1 = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12)
, c2 = c(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22)
, c3 = as.character(as.integer(c(0:12, 0:2)))
, c4 = as.character(as.integer(c(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  55)))
, c5 = as.character(as.integer(c(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76)))
)  %\>% copy_to(sc, ., "tmp", T)

d1 <- d %\>%
spark_apply(function(df)
tidyr::pivot_wider(
df,
id_cols = c(c1, c2),
names_from = c3,
values_from = c(c4, c5)
))
```

#> d1

```
#>  c1    c2 c4_0  c4_1  c4_2  c4_3  c4_4  c4_5  c4_6  c4_7  c4_8  c4_9  c5_0  c5_1  c5_2  c5_3  c5_4  c5_5  c5_6  c5_7  c5_8  c5_9
#>   \<dbl\> \<dbl\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\> \<chr\>
#>  1    11    21 40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50    51    52    61    62    63    64    65    66    67  
#>  2    12    22 53    54    55    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    74    75    76    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

#> colnames(d1)

```
#>  [1] "c1"   "c2"   "c4_0" "c4_1" "c4_2" "c4_3" "c4_4" "c4_5" "c4_6" "c4_7" "c4_8" "c4_9" "c5_0" "c5_1" "c5_2" "c5_3" "c5_4" "c5_5" "c5_6" "c5_7" "c5_8" "c5_9"
```

In C3 we have 13 columns (0 to12) but only 10 (0-9) are generated.
In the results: Values are pivoted correctly but only 9 names are generated. In the result, c4_10 to c4_12 columns are not there but values are present (c5_0 to c5_2). Actual value of c5_0 is getting printed from c5_3.

I am not sure, what is going wring here

I tried different functions with names_repair but no success. Still getting only 9 columns